# PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-settings

I have a dell XPS 15 laptop (GTX 960M) with Ubuntu 16.04 installed which is connected to **two dell monitors**.

After installing the nvidia drivers via Sofware & Updates (I am using NVIDIA binary drivers version 378.09 from nvidia-378) I proceed to "NVIDIA X Server Settings" to configure which of my monitors will be the primary one.

**Sadly, I am unable to configure the primary monitor and the monitors layout**. All screens in "X Server Display Configuration" are shaded and with the following note:

"PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings and must be configured by an external RandR capable tool. The display is shown in the layout window for information purposes only".
(see [NVIDIA X Server Setting screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRY1S.png))

I am not sure if this is due to the nvidia drivers I installed or another issue alltogether. I checked on [nvidia-drivers site](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk) and for my graphics card (GTX 960M) there are no drivers for a 64 bit linux OS, only 32.

If anybody has a solution such that I can configure my screens, choose primary display and which is to the left and right, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my recent revised solution on Ubuntu 18.04 to get screen synchronization on my External Monitor to ...

... STOP SCREEN TEARING!! with Nvidia Drivers in use

04/12/18
∘ **PRIME Synchronization on Optimus**

To check:

`sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset`

It Should say "y" for modeset=1, for your Monitor ex. HDMI-1-1, or  eDP-1-1

To get PRIME Synchronization on Optimus when it says "N" for **NO** , create a new file in  /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf`

And make sure the following line is present;

> options nvidia-drm modeset=1

And after a Reboot or Update Intramfs
Here is the Update Intramfs code
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Now `sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset`, will give a Y for Yes, and screen tearing is greatly reduced!

Comment: Great :) it works for Lenovo legion y720

Comment: Fantastic! I had been struggling for years with my Lenovo Y700 and this finally solved it on Pop!_OS 18.04.

Comment: unfortunately for me it disables one of 2 external monitors (Ubuntu 18.04, dell precision 7520, 2 external monitors + laptop's monitor)

Comment: This tecnique of Prime Synchronization (putting `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` inside a config file in `modprobe.d`) completely broke my system. At restart, kubuntu restarted into a black screen. After 3 hours the solution was to remove a corrupted xorg.conf file: `mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, with driver version 440.82 on an MX250

Comment: Recent versions of PRIME as with Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia driver 440 do control the modeset with the file `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf` so all other solutions will not work or might mess things up.

Comment: unfortunately, this method not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: even if it says "y" - create that file and update initramfs. Works like a charm on Kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

Use the native **Displays** settings panel:

[image: Displays Settings]

You can open this by going to  **System Settings** and selecting **Displays**, or by just searching for Displays in the Dash.